# Multiple counter_cache in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails, and got into a little problem. I'm writing dead simple app with lists of tasks, so models look something like that:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :undone_tasks, :class_name => 'Task',
                          :foreign_key => 'task_id',
                          :conditions => 'done = false'
  # ... some validations
end
```

Table for `List` model has columns `tasks_counter` and `undone_tasks_counter`.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list, :counter_cache => true
  # .. some validations
end
```

With such code there is `attr_readonly :tasks_counter` for `List` instances but I would like to have a counter for undone tasks as well. Is there any way of having multiple counter cached automagically by Rails.

So far, I've managed to create `TasksObserver` that increments or decrements `Task#undone_tasks_counter`, but maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: did you figure it out in the end?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried it with a custom-counter-cache column?
The doc here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

It suggests that you can pass a column-name to the counter_cache option, which you may well be able to call twice eg

```
belongs_to :list, :counter_cache => true     # will setup tasks_count
belongs_to :list, :counter_cache => :undone_tasks_count
```

Note: not actually tested.

Comment: That actually worked. Didn't used the SO account for quite some time, thanks for such clean solution!

Comment: I just tried this and the result was the second cache incrementing twice and the first not at all. I guess something changed in the last year?

Comment: @Steven you're right. According to the Rails API, you can now just specify the name of the column, thus saving you an additional step.

Comment: This may have been correct at the time of writing, but now the line ```belongs_to :list, :counter_cache => true``` will expect a column named ```tasks_count``` defined on the ```lists``` table, not ```tasks_counter``` (see the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)).

Comment: This works with the example given but it fails when you have 2 named counter columns :(

Comment: It is not working for multiple counter columns with same association like belongs_to list here. I am getting the same results as @steven and jamesfzhang said above.

Comment: This answer was posted five years ago... it would not surprise me if Rails has moved on in that time :( Might be worth looking into the more recent docs for counter-cache to see how it's supposed to work now? If you figure it out, let me know and I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ez way.

**1)  first counter - will do automatically**

**2) Manually "correct"**

```
  AnotherModelHere

    belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :first_friends_count


    after_create  :provide_correct_create_counter_2
    after_destroy :provide_correct_destroy_counter_2

    def provide_correct_create_counter_2
      User.increment_counter(:second_friends_count, another_user.id)
    end

    def provide_correct_destroy_counter_2
      User.decrement_counter(:second_friends_count, another_user.id)
    end
```

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you will need [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem, as it can handle counters with custom conditions and will update counter value not only on create and destroy, but for updates too:

```
class CreateContainers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  create_table :containers, comment: 'Our awesome containers' do |t|
    t.integer  :items_count,        default: 0, null: false, comment: 'Caching counter for total items'
    t.integer  :loaded_items_count, default: 0, null: false, comment: 'Caching counter for loaded items'
  end
end

class Container < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :items, inverse_of: :container
  has_many   :loaded_items, -> { where.not(loaded_at: nil) }, 
             class_name: 'Item',
             counter_cache: :loaded_items_count
             # Notice that you can specify custom counter cache column name
             # in has_many definition and AR will use it!
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :container, inverse_of: :items, counter_cache: true
  counter_culture :container, column_name: proc { |model| model.loaded_at.present? ? 'loaded_items_count' : nil }
  # But this column value will be handled by counter_culture gem
end
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not aware of any "automagical" method for this. Observers seems good for this, but I personally prefer using callbacks in model (`before_save`, `after_save`).